# Adding custom properties the Document Object in front-end javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters

Is it ok to add custom properties the Document Object in front-end javascript?

Suppose I want to store some parameters, but I can't do so in the URL.  Can I create a new property on the Document Object to store the parameters?  For example, if my parameter is 'someImportantInfo', can I set:

```
document.someImportantInfo = 'thisIsSecretInfo';
```

So that when a user goes new page, I can retrieve the contents of the 'someImportantInfo' property in my front-end Javascript, and do something with 'thisIsSecretInfo'?

Comment: So you're trying to pass info between pages? You'd be far better off to make use of `cookies`, a `session` or `localStorage` for that. And if it's "secret info", you'd probably want a whole database -- all client-side JavaScript is exposed to the end-user.

Comment: document.someImportantInfo  is not a good idea anybody can hack this object, you can use as per above comment, else if you are aware of Redux `https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux` , can also use

Comment: The info is not secret in my case, it's OK if the end-user finds out what it is.  I was thinking if there was any flaw in me doing this.  If Mozilla decides that my attribute name 'someImportantInfo' is now a reserved keyword, then maybe.  But what else?

Comment: Mozilla reserving the keyword is the least of your problems. You will lose JavaScript state when you move across pages or reload the page. The localStorage option described above is simplest, other options being to use AJAX always and then maintain a state model in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is not in the document Object.

When you load a new page, the document Object will be replaced by another one.

To store information between different pages you can use the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`:

When you need to save some value:

```
localStorage.setItem("someImportantInfo","thisIsSecretInfo");
```

And when you need to get this value in other page:

```
localStorage.getItem("someImportantInfo");
```

See some examples in: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

If you want to store information only during a session (cleared when the browser is closed), use `sessionStorage` instead.

Also, you can use cookies, but it's more tricky because you don't have a native function to save and retrieve cookies.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.